# How to overshadow a package from repository with another version?

Tags: pkg-config

I have a glib-2.0 2.36.0 package, installed from ubuntu repo. So now

```
pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0
```

Prints `2.36.0` Recently, I downloaded and built a fresh new version `2.40.0`. I need it to build a Clutter, also downloaded manually. It requires glib version 2.37.3 at least.

How can I point out a custom pkgconfig directory, that is located in the glib binaries such, that `--modversion` will return `2.40.0`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` :

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$PKG_CONFIG_PATH $HOME/frameworks/glib/lib/pkgconfig/" pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0
```

Gives the right result.